# Can I create this in CSS? If so, how?

Tags: css

Is this design possible at all in CSS? If so, how should I go about building it out?

[image]

Do note that the white is the "bottom" part of the design, which overlays on top of an image.

Comment: Off-hand I'd say it is (given you can make an [assortment of CSS shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)...)

Comment: sure, but it will take a lot of time and it's probably not worth it.

Comment: I've been trying to do so, but my CSS-fu is not good enough I guess ;/  (btw Brad - the Infinity shape in your link is impressive)

Comment: this will work, try this for the blue field:
transform:rotate(30deg);

Comment: background with image and linear-gradient , background-size ... looks like a slider ? ... you do not giv enough code of yours to tell if it's possible and how , is the image to be cut or is it a translucide png, what HTML structure, wich slider if any , and so on ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, using clip-path. On codepen: http://codepen.io/marcellods/pen/lwqAJ

HTML:

```
  <div class="masked">
    <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/480/260/sports/" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masked img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0
  );
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0
  );
    -ms-clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0
  );
    clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0
  );
}

.page {
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: #47BCDA;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.masked + .masked {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Good read on the matter at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/
Another codepen with clip-path shapes: http://codepen.io/Darsain/pen/IqjFe

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This'll do with some z-index'd divs for the blue area

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can, but it's probably not worth it. Too much extra code when simple bg images will work perfectly well.

If you must use CSS, make a few properly z-indexed divs and rotate them with `transform: rotate(25deg);`

Comment: plenty other way to achieve this static screenshot in css , but not enough code and explanation to my taste from jsanc623 to give some advice, :)

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to achieve this. You can even use border triangles and position them accordingly. But is it worth it? Nah, just make an image man.

Comment: Needs to be responsive though, hence why CSS was my first thought

Comment: just use a width:100% on the image and when the containers resize, so will the image ;-)

Comment: Doh! Spent a good hour getting it all perfect and responsive with clip-path and a blue background xD

Comment: glad you figured it out!